# Docker + Ubuntu + Virtualbox: "volumes" directive in dockerfile not working

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, docker-compose, docker-machine

Just testing Docker here and already in front an issue: the ["volumes" directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) in dockerfile seems like not working in Ubuntu -- OK in Mac and Windows. All the proccess with [docker-machine](/questions/tagged/docker-machine) and [docker-compose](/questions/tagged/docker-compose) alright and the environment ups, but the filesystem without the sharing folders.

After trying MANY things and a lot of researching with my pals, we found this issue in GitHub: "[Add support to mount Linux host homedir](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/pull/1086)".

Basically, the problem is the fail of Docker in mount host home dir in container. They plan to include the fix in future releases, but, meanwhile, if you need to use right now, here is what you have to do.

Open Virtualbox interface, right click in your machine, Settings > Shared Folders. You can delete whatever is filled and add a new one. In path, choose your `/home` and name `Users` (could be whatever name, but this one is for name consistency with Mac and Windows). Check automatic mounting and persistence and press "OK".

[image: Virtualbox config sample]

After that, you enter in your machine with `docker-machine ssh [name]` and you have to create a symlink to the `/home` of the guest from your shared home folder in docker (host already mapped):

`ln -s "/Users/[your username]/${d}" "/home/${d}"`

From here, the mapping must be alright and you good to go!  \o/

**PS to frontenders**: if you intend to use [LiveReload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) in your projects, you need to run `vboxmanage controlvm default natpf1 "35729,tcp,127.0.0.1,35729,,35729"` in your terminal (not inside docker machine, in host) -- just once for all projects.

Comment: This is very useful, but in order to be visible that the question has an answer do this, update your post and leave only the question/problem. Take the solution and post it as an answer and then mark it. That way the thread will be viewed as answered.

Comment: Ermmm.  Where is the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just testing Docker here and already in front an issue: the ["volumes" directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) in dockerfile seems like not working in Ubuntu -- OK in Mac and Windows. All the proccess with [docker-machine](/questions/tagged/docker-machine) and [docker-compose](/questions/tagged/docker-compose) alright and the environment ups, but the filesystem without the sharing folders.

After trying MANY things and a lot of researching with my pals, we found this issue in GitHub: "[Add support to mount Linux host homedir](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/pull/1086)".

Basically, the problem is the fail of Docker in mount host home dir in container. They plan to include the fix in future releases, but, meanwhile, if you need to use right now, here is what you have to do.

Open Virtualbox interface, right click in your machine, Settings > Shared Folders. You can delete whatever is filled and add a new one. In path, choose your `/home` and name `Users` (could be whatever name, but this one is for name consistency with Mac and Windows). Check automatic mounting and persistence and press "OK".

[image: Virtualbox config sample]

After that, you enter in your machine with `docker-machine ssh [name]` and you have to create a symlink to the `/home` of the guest from your shared home folder in docker (host already mapped):

`ln -s "/Users/[username]/${d}" "/home/${d}"`

From here, the mapping must be alright and you good to go!  \o/

**PS to frontenders**: if you intend to use [LiveReload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) in your projects, you need to run `vboxmanage controlvm default natpf1 "35729,tcp,127.0.0.1,35729,,35729"` in your terminal (not inside docker machine, in host) -- just once for all projects.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think it's real bug in docker-machine. If i use docker all volume permission work fine, but if if run docker under docker-machine i can't fix it. Now i use Pycharm with interpreter from container, but debug and do all other thing from console in docker. It's not so very comfortable, but all autocomplite work fine.