# File not found in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm doing something extremely simple.  Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ADD hello.sh /bin/hello
RUN chmod +x /bin/hello

CMD /bin/hello
```

Then I build the image:

```
docker build -t hello .
```

Then I run the image:

```
docker run hello
```

And here is the output:

```
/bin/sh: /bin/hello: not found
```

Why is this happening?  If I run:

```
docker run hello cat /bin/hello
```

I can see the content of my script, which makes me even more confused.

Comment: I replicated your steps above using my own docker image, and it worked just fine, no problems.  So, the issue must be with the docker image you are basing off of.  The file clearly exists.  This has to be a permissions issue.  You should check to see what user you are by default, your permissions, etc.  Can you point us to the `Dockerfile` that alpine came from, and we can give more specifics?

Comment: After doing some more thinking, I have another hypothesis.  The entrypoint for the docker image could be changing your user, or messing with your bash terminal.  Try running this `docker run -it hello bash`, and then running `hello` once inside of the container (and post the output).  That would tell us if the `entrypoint` and/or `CMD` for the image is doing something strange.  The reason why your second example would have worked is because it was overriding the `CMD` of the Dockerfile specifically.

Comment: Hi @CtheGood, thanks for looking into this issue.  Your comment made me thinking and I do think that it's some sort of user/group/permission issues.  So I wrote the script on a ubuntu computer and I'm trying to run it in an alpine image, and that seems to be what's causing the problem.  Once I switched to an ubuntu image, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved by using an ubuntu image instead of an alpine image.  Not exactly sure why, but might have to do with the file's user/permission bits getting copied over and not interpreted correctly.

Comment: It can be different shell issue as well! You can try checking the current shell.

Comment: That solved my issue, but I'm still very unsatisfied: what *was* the reason?

Comment: See my answer below. His script is likely trying to use bash but bash is not in alpine OS by default. Changing his shebang line to /bin/sh would've fixed this instead of switching to ubuntu (which has bash installed by default)

Comment: Sheesh, thank you!  Not the first time I've been bitten by Alpine.  For me this happened when building in WSL2.  I thought it was a \r\n problem, but nope, it was Alpine.

Answer (score 13):

In my case the problem was that the **line-endings for the script** were `Windows` encoded instead of `Linux`.  (Note: This was actually caused by `git` automatically converting them, which I disabled)

The first line of the script provides the file path to the shell. Because of the extra `\r` that is included with Windows EOL the system was trying attaching that hidden character to the filename and that's what caused the `Not Found` error.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like you were trying to execute a `bash` script but alpine by default does not include `bash`. Instead you need to have your script execute using `sh` by changing your shebang line to be `#!/bin/sh`.

In effect, the script is being executed but it's actually saying that `/bin/bash` does not exist.

Comment: Most likely answer. Also, you might be able to use `/bin/ash` (Almquist Shell) but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 6):

The file not found can be from:

- the file actually isn't there, check for typos, make sure you aren't trying to run a quoted command and all the arguments together when you should only be running the command (not this issue, but seen it many times). And make sure you aren't mounting a volume over top of where you expect your command.
- the command at the top of the script doesn't exist. E.g. trying to call bash when the container only has sh. This also applies to those that create the script on Windows and have invalid line feeds at the end of the command. I don't believe Alpine includes a bash where other base images do.
- the binary you are trying to run links libraries that do not exist inside the container. This is seen with Alpine with the musl libc version differences.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem where, no matter how my python app was simple (imagine just hello.py that outputs 'hello world'), when running through docker-compose build && up commands I got error hello.py - not found.
It turned out that the issue was that virtualbox did not mount my folder (app) properly. This came as a rescue and resolved my problem in 5 minutes:
[Docker + Ubuntu + Virtualbox: "volumes" directive in dockerfile not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005974/docker-ubuntu-virtualbox-volumes-directive-in-dockerfile-not-working/35013305#35013305)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes