# Dockerfile RUN command throws an error but on different machines it works fine

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile there's a RUN command like this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.1.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04
...
RUN ./my_script.sh
```

The first line in the script is `#!/bin/bash`. My colleagues are able to build the image with no problems, their OS is Linux Ubuntu 22.04. I use WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04) on Windows 11 to build the image with `docker compose build` and I get the following error:

```
ERROR [application 10/11] RUN ./my_script.sh 
0.426 /bin/sh: 1: ./my_script.sh: not found
```

I have two questions, because I don't understand why this error happens:

1. why RUN command behaves differently on different machines? The container OS is the same and the RUN command runs inside the container, right?
2. why the error reports `/bin/sh` even if in the script `/bin/bash` is declared?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OS you are running it on. You probably are just not doing *exactly* the same thing your colleagues are doing. How is the `my_script.sh` file copied into the container? What does your [build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/) vs. those of your colleagues look like i. e. from which directory do you run the build command? Have you tried building the single image with `docker build`?

Comment: We start exactly from the same place, i.e. the root folder of the project. We're on the same git branch. The script is copied with along with all other content with COPY . /application command in Dockerfile. I tried to execute the script directly form inside the container and it also throws the same error

Comment: What's the output of `ls` e.g. when you use `RUN ls && ./my_script.sh`? Do you see the file? You can also do that in earlier steps to e.g. verify that they copy has worked.

Comment: When you RUN the image (are you sure you mean here "RUN" and not "CMD"), you basically execute `/bin/sh -c './my_script.sh'`.  Your #! line is not relevant  yet at this point. The error message suggests that the script does not exist. For debugging, change your command to `RUN ls -l && ./my_sript.sh`

Comment: I mean RUN, not CMD. The file is there. When I modify the command into `RUN bash ./my_script.sh` it works fine. My question is why my colleagues don't have to modify the command by adding `bash` and it still works on their machines.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36001786/596285

Comment: Note that `/bin/sh` is because of the syntax of the RUN step, any string that isn't a JSON array is passed to the shell to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This frequently happens when Git on Windows is configured to change line endings to CR-LF, instead of the Linux LF standard. That changes the interpreter for the script from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash\r`. Adjust the Git configuration to preserve the line endings from the code to avoid this issue.