# Docker container volume doesn't write to host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-machine, docker-volume

Hi i try to generate some assets within a docker container and put it to a host. All that is running within a docker-machine environment initialised with virtualbox driver.

for example i run:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD/testfolder:/var/www:rw ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and then

```
root@b9e73827bc3c:/var/www touch dummy.txt
```

from that point i actually have to see `dummy.txt` in my host's `$PWD/testfolder` folder, but there is neither a folder **testfolder** nor ***dummy.txt*** in it(logicly).

The weired thing, the same setup works correct on MacOSX and creates files on a host end, but when i tried it Ubuntu:14.04 it stopped working.
here are both container `inspect` on

- MacOSX host: https://gist.github.com/zavalit/65e8a260866f834223616c1b59e4ce7d
- Ubuntu:14.04 host: 
  https://gist.github.com/zavalit/40bd3ce8629ad81fcd6793ca63f99491

as far as i can see, they are both quite identical.

it tried it with both docker-machine version 0.7.0-rc2 and 0.6.0, docker version is 1.10.3

did anyone experienced, stuff like that? i'm pretty much appreciate any possible tipps. thx.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to manually setuo your VM to bind folders with your local machine.
You can follow these instructions : 
[Docker + Ubuntu + Virtualbox: "volumes" directive in dockerfile not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005974/docker-ubuntu-virtualbox-volumes-directive-in-dockerfile-not-working)

But, why are you using a VM under ubuntu?
You can use docker without any VM under Linux systems.

Comment: thx, but it didn't really help a lot: i runned ```VBoxManage sharedfolder add "VM name" --name "Users" --hostpath "/home"``` and then symlinked it in a VM as it was in a linked example, it got complete access to my host user, but it still doesn't mount properly.

Answer (score 0):

You must not run docker inside docker machine if you are on linux. You can install it using apt https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/.

It does not required docker-machine and it is not a good idea to use it.

What you want to do works fine using docker on linux (without docker machine).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are running the `docker run` after you issue a `docker-machine ssh`

In that case your files are inside the VM.

If running `docker run` in your host gives you error or doesn't run the engine in your VM, you must issue first:

```
. docker-machine env
```

Regards